# Aurelia-validation error message not showing with Polymer paper-input element

Tags: polymer, aurelia

I'm trying to use aurelia-validation with the Polymer components.

I cannot get the validation error messages to append to the label part of the paper-input element.

It has an embedded label and I can't see why it should not work. In a debug session I can see that the validation has failed.

If I put another label into the same form-group it works fine but it's attached to the wrong label.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show some code. Also can you accept an answer on your existing questions.

Comment: The code is not at fault. I have looked at the code in the Aurelia-Validation classes and it is because it only recurses 5 times  looking for the embedded label element. I increased it to 10 and it worked.

I still have a few things to resolve regarding the styling to show the validation message where I want it but that's my problem I think.